# Ipython notebook not working on my Firefox browser, even though the command prompt window seems to be fine

Tags: firefox, ipython

I've been using IPython ever since I can remember (and I have a pretty good memory), both for Python and for Julia. However, lately there seems to be an issue with getting it to work on my browser. I use ver. 50.1.0 of FF and my IP software is up-to-date. The program launches fine (i.e. without any errors), initiating a local host at port 8888, but the browser never gets the memo to start a new tab to render whatever IPython sends to that address. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has to do with some update or something that I've done recently. When I go to the local host address I can access the notebook. Even though this is less than ideal, as I have to take an additional step in order to use IPython, it's not crucial.

Comment: if this is a reproducible problem with ipython not initiating the browser then you could open an issue with them. Else if you want to delve deeper you could try checking what your default browser is and whether other applications are able to launch it OK.

Comment: FF is my default browser (I'm not a newbie). Also, I've used IPython for years before the problem manifested. I will check to see if the browser is problematic after the latest update, or if there is something else interfering. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: The downvotes on the Q may have been for its brevity, difficult to say. However we discourage commentary about voting in posts themselves, since it is not of interest to most readers. Put it in comments if you really must, but I think it is a waste of time - voters click and move on, unfortunately!